# MVC change the contain without refresh the default view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Now I am try to do like this in mvc3 , when I click refresh or change the page, it was refresh whole thing and before that there will become a blank page. Now what I want is when I click the refresh button or go to another views, only some part of page is change. Let say I have 3  : header , main , and footer.
The header and footer will be the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Layout` for this in MVC 3, in your project created there is an **Layout.cshtml** file which you could use for this.

Layout acts like what Master pages was in .aspx web forms.

> This file is present at Views > Shared > Layout.cshtml

Here you can define the so called header and footer, which in this file comes predefined and now whenever you want to use this Layout in your view, you simply need to include this line in  your view.

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Some Title";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Also, if you open the Layout.cshtml somewhere between the `<header>` and the `<footer>` tag you will find the following lines of code...

```
<section id="main">
    <div>
    @RenderBody()
    </div>
</section>
```

The `@RenderBody` line of code written in the Layout.cshtml will automatically place the content of the view between the header and footer section

and Welcome to Stackoverflow ! :)